# How many CNOT gates are needed to compute scalar multiplication in a finite field of characteristic 2?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, finite-fields

I want to know if scalar multiplication over a finite field of characteristic 2 is generally easier to compute than a linear transformation over a vector space over $F_{2}$.

Suppose that $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $F_{2}$ of degree $n$.
Then $F_{2}[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a finite field of cardinality $2^{n}$.

Define an operation $*$ on $\{0,1\}^{n}$ where
$$(a_{0},...,a_{n-1})*(b_{0},...,b_{n-1})=(c_{0},...,c_{n-1})$$ precisely when
$$(a_{0}+...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1})\cdot(b_{0}+...+b_{n-1}x^{n-1})/\langle p(x)\rangle=c_{0}+...+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}/\langle p(x)\rangle.$$

Let $C_{i,j}:\{0,1\}^{n-1}\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{n-1}$ be the mapping defined by
$$C_{i,j}(x_{1},...,x_{n})=(x_{1},...,x_{i},...,x_{i}\oplus x_{j},...,x_{n}).$$
In other words, $C_{i,j}$ corresponds to the matrix $A$ with $1$'s along the diagonal, a $1$ in the $(j,i)$-th entry and $0$'s elsewhere ($A\mathbf{x}=C_{i,j}\mathbf{x}$).

Each $C_{i,j}$ is an elementary linear transformation and each $C_{i,j}$ is a CNOT gate $(x,y)\mapsto(x,x\oplus y)$. Suppose that $\mathbf{r}=(r_{0},...,r_{n-1}),\mathbf{r}\neq 0$ and $t_{p(x),\mathbf{r}}$ is the least number $m$ such that there are $C_{i_{m},j_{m}},...,C_{i_{1},j_{1}}$ where
$(r_{0},...,r_{n-1})*(x_{0},...,x_{n-1})=C_{i_{m},j_{m}}\circ...\circ C_{i_{1},j_{1}}(x_{0},...,x_{n-1})$
whenever $x_{0},...,x_{n-1}\in\{0,1\}$. What are some bounds for the number $t_{p(x),\mathbf{r}}$?

Comment: What bounds do you know for general linear transformations?

Comment: The paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939190217V gives an upper bound of $n^{2}+n-2$ for general invertible matrices over $F_{2}$. For random general invertible matrices over $F_{2}$, I have obtained a lower bound of about $\frac{n^{2}}{\ln(n)}\cdot\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$. I want to know if scalar multiplication in $F_{2^{n}}$ can in general be computed in much less than $n^{2}$ CNOT gates though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the formula for $C_{i,j}$. Is it just that $x_j$ is replaced by $x_i\oplus x_j$?

Comment: Gerry. Yes. $x_{j}$ becomes $x_{i}\oplus x_{j}$. I edited the post to make that more clear.

Comment: My lower bound bound around $\frac{n^{2}}{\ln(n)}\cdot\frac{\ln(2)}{2}$ can probably be improved to somewhere near $n^{2}$ by better calculations.

Comment: There is an upper bound of $\frac{n^2}{\log_2 n}(1+o(1))$; see the discussion in https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.5826